# Join two rdds in Spark where first rdd's value is second rdd's key

Tags: pyspark, left-join, rdd

There two rdds, the first one is a (key, value) pair `rdd_1`:

```
key1,[value1, value2]
```

the second one is also a (key, value) pair `rdd_2`:

```
(key2, value3), (key3, value4)...
```

I want join `rdd1` and `rdd2` , and `rdd_1`'s `value1` & `value2` is the `key2` in `rdd2`. The result that I want is

```
key1, [value1: value3, value2: value4]
```

I can process `rdd1` with flatMap and then change the order, which means:

```
key1,[value1, value2] -> (key1, value1),(key1, value2)->(value1, key1),(value2, key1)
```

then to join `rdd2`, and then to change order & merge with key1...
Is there a more efficient to do it? thx.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use dataframe, much faster than rdd's.
With dataframes, you can do something like this

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
x = [(0, [1,2]),(1,[7,8])]
y = [(1,4),(2,6),(8,4), (7,3)]

x = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(x)).toDF("id", "vals")
y = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(y)).toDF("id2", "val")

(x.join(y,  f.expr("array_contains(vals, id2)")).select("id", 
                                                       f.struct(["id2", "val"]).alias("map")).
                                                        groupBy("id").agg(f.collect_list("map").alias("map"))).show()



+---+--------------+
| id|           map|
+---+--------------+
|  0|[[1,4], [2,6]]|
|  1|[[8,4], [7,3]]|
+---+--------------+
```